# How to back up OWA exchange emails without Outlook

Tags: email, backup, thunderbird, exchange, outlook-web-access

My university uses Microsoft Outlook Web Access (OWA) e-mail. Soon they will close my e-mail account as my course has ended, but I really do not want to lose the archive of emails and attachments.

I've read a backup to something called a `.pst` can be made if one has access to `Microsoft Outlook` but I do not.

Is there any other way I could back these up? (preferably on Ubuntu 12.04 but I also have access to Win 7 if need be).

One idea I played with is using `davmail` to allow access via Thunderbird and performing some kind of backup with that. However, I cannot seem to get past `Authentication failed: invalid user or password, retry with domain\user`.

Comment: an ugly option might be to get a trial version of outlook, then use thunderbird to import from that. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files has a few options that might be worth testing out as well

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try. I also got Thunderbird and Davmail to work (by setting `davmail.enableEws=false`). Does Thunderbird automatically make local copies of my mail to my hard drive (will the folders showing now still be there even when the account is closed?, i.e. If I were to just copy the .profile folder and restore it on a different computer) or do I need to explicitly make local copies somehow?

Comment: I believe you can set it to under account settings -> copies and folders. At this rate you're going to self answer, so don't forget to do so once you have worked this out.

Answer (score 1):

On `Ubuntu`, install  [davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/download.html) and follow the instructions on their website for setting up Thunderbird. In particular you may need `domain\user` rather than just `user` and I needed
`davmail.enableEws=false` in the properties file. When the OWA mail is working with Thunderbird, go to `account settings->copies and folders` and set up a local archive. Finally, select mails to back up and archive them to the local folder.

Even better: use the addon `ImportExportTools` to create local html copies with attachments of all your folders.